# sqlalchemy_utils PasswordType db constraints

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am wondering if there any possibility to apply constraints for the PasswordType field of sqlaclchemy_utils?

Currently, my constraints are not working for it:

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):

    password = db.Column(
        PasswordType(
            max_length=60,
            schemes=[
                'pbkdf2_sha512',
                'md5_crypt'
            ],
            deprecated=['md5_crypt']
        ),
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
    )

    __table_args__ = (
        db.CheckConstraint('length("password") >= 7', name='password_min_length')
```

Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As constraints are applied on the value that is already stored in a DB and the PasswordType is hashing the value of a password, constraints are applied directly to the hash. Therefore a validation should be used somewhere else, like views, where the password value is still not stored to the DB and is of a row representation.